# How can I determine the accuracy of correlation?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, reliability, validity, spurious-correlation

When I performed correlation analysis of C02 emission with around four-hundred attributes, i found out that C02 emission and cereal production has a correlation value of 0.98 where as the most obvious of indicator like population had only 0.2 correlation with C02 emission,
So how to determine  whether my correlation score is correct or not ?

Comment: state the hypothesis and objective of measuring two different correlations. what is correlation score ?

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether your corr coefficient is different from population's 0.

I guess statsmodels in Python have a module for that.

Here is an easy-to-read theory:

http://www.real-statistics.com/regression/hypothesis-testing-significance-regression-line-slope/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by 'correct'. If the significance level is high (which I assume it is), than you have a very small chance that this correlation came from a population without a correlation at all. It does not mean that in the population the relationship is almost perfect as in your sample, but it is likely high, given enough observations.

However, this does not imply a causation. Simple Pearson correlation just shows a relationship, but this can have other underlying variables that are responsible for the relationship. It could even prove non-significant (or much less powerful). For this to come to light, however, a form of regression is recommended. Try thinking (or looking at literature) which variables can theoretically interfere in such a relationship, and put them all in a model.
It might prove worth your while.

Comment: Does number of observations matters while performing correlation between two variable ?

Comment: The number of observations always matters insofar that the more observations you have, the easier it is to get statistically significant results. In a sense, even the most minuscule correlation - in the population - is, well, significant. So Yes. But unless you have a very small (<30) sample size in a bivariate correlation model, don't worry about it to much.

Comment: @Yuvual , I have 1000 to 15000 variable which are all World development indicators provided by World Bank ,so lets say A and B have a correlation of 0.9, and  B has a high corr with 4 or 5 other variable in the data set.Can i put those 5 variable in the model rather than referring literature as you have mentioned ?

Comment: You can, but: (1) unless you deal with machine learning, where the 'why' is not as important as the how, than you need to be able to rationalize your variable selection from a theoretically satisfying point of view. (2) no matter what you do with the first point, you must be sure that given very high correlations, you don't get multicollinearity - several dependent variables which are not really dependent. Check VIF test and read a bit about collinearity - it can seriously mess with the coefficients and their significance values.